installed podofo from vcpkg but keep getting is not a member of PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument
I used 'vcpkg install podofo' to get podofo
here is code I tried to build
#include <podofo/podofo.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace PoDoFo;

void mergePDFs(const std::vector<std::string>& inputFiles, const std::string& outputFile) {
    PdfMemDocument outputPdf;

    try {
        for (const auto& file : inputFiles) {
            PdfMemDocument pdf;
            pdf.Load(file.c_str());

            for (int i = 0; i < pdf.GetPageCount(); ++i) {
                PdfPage* page = pdf.GetPage(i);
                outputPdf.InsertPage(page, outputPdf.GetPageCount());
            }
        }

        outputPdf.Write(outputFile.c_str());
        std::cout << "PDF files merged successfully into " << outputFile << std::endl;
    } catch (PdfError& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error merging PDF files: " << e.GetError() << std::endl;
    }
}

void changePageOrder(const std::string& inputFile, const std::string& outputFile) {
    try {
        PdfMemDocument pdf;
        pdf.Load(inputFile.c_str());

        int pageCount = pdf.GetPageCount();
        PdfMemDocument outputPdf;

        int front = 0;
        int back = pageCount - 1;

        while (front <= back) {
            if (front <= back) {
                PdfPage* page = pdf.GetPage(front);
                outputPdf.InsertPage(page, outputPdf.GetPageCount());
                ++front;
            }

            if (front <= back) {
                PdfPage* page = pdf.GetPage(back);
                outputPdf.InsertPage(page, outputPdf.GetPageCount());
                --back;
            }
        }

        outputPdf.Write(outputFile.c_str());
        std::cout << "Page order changed successfully in " << outputFile << std::endl;
    } catch (PdfError& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error changing page order: " << e.GetError() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        int choice;
        std::cout << "Menu:\n";
        std::cout << "1. Merge PDFs\n";
        std::cout << "2. Change Page Order\n";
        std::cout << "3. Merge and Change Page Order\n";
        std::cout << "4. Exit\n";
        std::cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                std::vector<std::string> inputFiles;
                std::string filename;

                std::cout << "Enter PDF filenames to merge (enter 'done' to finish):\n";
                while (true) {
                    std::cin >> filename;
                    if (filename == "done") break;
                    inputFiles.push_back(filename);
                }

                std::string outputFile;
                std::cout << "Enter output PDF filename: ";
                std::cin >> outputFile;

                mergePDFs(inputFiles, outputFile);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                std::string inputFile, outputFile;
                std::cout << "Enter PDF filename to reorder: ";
                std::cin >> inputFile;
                std::cout << "Enter output PDF filename: ";
                std::cin >> outputFile;

                changePageOrder(inputFile, outputFile);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                std::vector<std::string> inputFiles;
                std::string filename;

                std::cout << "Enter PDF filenames to merge (enter 'done' to finish):\n";
                while (true) {
                    std::cin >> filename;
                    if (filename == "done") break;
                    inputFiles.push_back(filename);
                }

                std::string mergedFile;
                std::cout << "Enter intermediate merged PDF filename: ";
                std::cin >> mergedFile;

                mergePDFs(inputFiles, mergedFile);

                std::string reorderedFile;
                std::cout << "Enter output PDF filename for reordered pages: ";
                std::cin >> reorderedFile;

                changePageOrder(mergedFile, reorderedFile);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
                std::cout << "Exiting the program.\n";
                return 0;
            default:
                std::cout << "Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.\n";
        }
    }
}

from developer cmd I used
cl /EHsc /std:c++17 PDFencil.cpp /I"E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include" /link /LIBPATH:"E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib" podofo.lib 
I think i made sure i included path correctly and used c++17
but I am getting
PDFencil.cpp(16): error C2039: 'GetPageCount': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(17): error C2039: 'GetPage': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(18): error C2039: 'InsertPage': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(18): error C2039: 'GetPageCount': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(22): error C2039: 'Write': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(25): error C2039: 'GetError': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfError'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfError.h(148): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfError'
PDFencil.cpp(34): error C2039: 'GetPageCount': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(42): error C2039: 'GetPage': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(43): error C2039: 'InsertPage': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(43): error C2039: 'GetPageCount': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(48): error C2039: 'GetPage': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(49): error C2039: 'InsertPage': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(49): error C2039: 'GetPageCount': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(54): error C2039: 'Write': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfMemDocument.h(37): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument'
PDFencil.cpp(57): error C2039: 'GetError': is not a member of 'PoDoFo::PdfError'
E:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfError.h(148): note: see declaration of 'PoDoFo::PdfError'

I have no idea how to fix this
This is my first time using external libraries
I double checked path to vcpkg files.
I also tried to git clone podofo and build it for past 7 days.
tried using vcpkg to download dependencies also tried using bootstrap.cmd on playground but it fail.

Related if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764777/c-pdf-parsing-extract-text-podofo-0-10-3

From the question I linked I expect that podofo changed the API of this class at some point and you have to call PoDoFo::PdfPageCollection& pagetree = pdf.GetPages(); to get the page tree then you can get the count and the pages.
